# How to read path with arabic characters in python?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to access to a folder with arabic characters in name and read the images with CV2 but got issue that's my code:

```
class_names = ['ا', 'ب', 'ت']

for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk(r'C:\Users\emady\Desktop\VS Code\HandWriten_Arabic\Train2'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname[:-1], filename))
        path2 = os.path.join(dirname, filename).encode("utf8").decode()
        image = cv2.imread(path2)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

But as shown at my screenshot the path2 is good and the arabic letter has been read but at opencv I got error

[image]

Comment: Looks that you have a non-ascii character after the image path and before the image name - is that a valid subdirectory?

Comment: Why do you have `path2.encode('utf-8').decode()`?  Why not just use `path2`, which is already Unicode?

Comment: @stateMachine yeah that exists folder called "ا" as you can see here class_names = ['ا', 'ب', 'ت'] those names of folders

Comment: @TimRoberts when i removed the .encode('utf-8).decode()  I got that error "imread_('C:\Users\emady\Desktop\VS Code\HandWriten_Arabic\Train2\╪º\AHCR_00001_Alf_End_12.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity"

Answer (score 1):

```
img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(path2, dtype=np.uint8),
                   cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

That's solved my issue